# Xamarin Picker - Selecteditem not working on pageload

Tags: xamarin

I got stuck with my picker which is being populated with the categories on the pageload . however I want the correct category of the product to be selected as selectitem but not working.

Your helps are appreciated.

My XAML:

```
<Picker x:Name="Picker_Cats" Title="-- Select Category --"  ItemsSource="{Binding AllCats}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CategoryName}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCat,Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="DarkGray" SelectedIndexChanged="Picker_Cats_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
```

My VM:

```
private ObservableCollection<Category> _AllCats;
public ObservableCollection<Category> AllCats
        {
            set
            {
                this._AllCats = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
            get
            {
                return this._AllCats;
            }
        }


        private Category _SelectedCat;
        public Category SelectedCat
        {           
           set
            {
                this._SelectedCat = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
            get
            {
                return this._SelectedCat;
            }
        }





        public ProdsMngtDetailViewModel(Product product , Category selectedcat)
        {
            GetCatsAsync();
            SelectedCat = selectedcat;
            SelectedProduct = product;
            CategoriesService cs = new CategoriesService();
            AllCats = cs.GetAllCats();
        }
```

I debugged my application and SelectedCat is getting my desired category value but the issue is that picker not selecting it.

Answer (score 0):

We could not set the value of **SelectedItem** directly . like

```
SelectedCat = selectedcat;
```

It need to be included in the **ItemsSource** of the picker .

In your case , you could modify it like following

```
public ProdsMngtDetailViewModel(Product product , Category selectedcat)
{
  GetCatsAsync();
  SelectedProduct = product;
  CategoriesService cs = new CategoriesService();
  AllCats = cs.GetAllCats();

  // set SelectedCat after init the AllCats 

  foreach (var model in AllCats)
  {
      if(model.CategoryName==selectedcat.CategoryName)
      {
          SelectedCat = model;
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Lucas,  Got your point and tested it but app now goes to break mode and receive below error .. please assist further .    System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'

Comment: What is index on your side? You could share your sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: Debugged the error , the above error was due to indexchanging.   Again tried and still picker not showing any selecteditem however the selectedcat showing the correct category picked up .. any ideas ?

Comment: Don't use `SelectedIndexChanged="Picker_Cats_SelectedIndexChanged"` since you had used MVVM . You could handle the logic in the set method of `SelectedCat` .

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the page is not displayed directly on inizial loading?
At this point I have problems that sound like your problem.
I load all the content pages at once and when I go to a specific page, the page does not refresh.
If this is the problem, then the cheapest solution would be to inizialize only the page that is requested at the same moment. (I hope it is not like that)